# Custom Dictionary usage in fckeditor/tinymce Editors

Tags: spell-checking

I have to add my custom Dictionary to fckeditor/ tinymce editor,so that my brand name,material name shouldn't be misspelled in editor when spellchecking happens.Can anyone suggest me to add custom dictionary to my editors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are a few TinyMCE spell check options that can use custom dictionaries.  The free solution is the PSpell/ASpell plugin that uses PSpell/ASpell on your server.
http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/spellchecker

A non-free solutions is JSpell, which allows you to alter the dictionary from the editor.
http://www.jspell.com/ajax-spell-checker.html

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, is to use tinyMCE+LanguageTool  (https://www.languagetool.org/)
LanguageTool its more like a spell checking engine, where you can even define your own grammatical rules, etc.

Its really powerful and free. :)

Its offered also an open source spellchecker plugin for tinyMCE. The custom dictionary and other custom things can also be setup when hosting the service dictionary in your own server.

The actual spellchecking plugin:
   https://github.com/automattic/atd-tinymce

[How to integrate](http://wiki.languagetool.org/integration-on-websites)
[General development overview](http://wiki.languagetool.org/development-overview)
[Main wiki](http://wiki.languagetool.org/)
[Interesting info about related custom dictionary files](http://wiki.languagetool.org/hunspell-support)

Comment: I don't see why would anyone put vote with -1 on consistent answer. (not best formatting agree, but it can already help someone)